# Fatal repository not found with Git

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and facing a problem and dont know how to solve it. I'm working with friends on a project on a server and we want to use Git so that it will be easy for us to manage our changes.

The project directory was already on the server but not managed by any version control.  I install git on the server and ran `git init` in the project directory followed by `git add *` and `git commit -m 'xxx'`.

On my local machine I installed git and tried

```
git clone https://path.to.the.server/project_directory/.git
```

to clone the project but it failed with the following error:

> Cloning into
>   'xxx'... fatal: repository 'path.to.the.server/project_directory/.git'
>   not found

I've been trying for weeks and need help, please.

Comment: Please take a look at the [Getting Git on a Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) chapter of the gitpro book. It should answer most - if not all - of your questions.

Comment: I read the document you indicated but steal have the "repositoy not found" error when trying to clone

Comment: Well, what have you done different? Or did you still try to achieve it the same way?

Comment: i created a clon o the server and tried to clone it on my machine as explained in the documentation

Comment: Please provide your new steps as an edit to your question. That should make things clearer.

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is in your url variable. Because this link looks doesn't available for any content.

Yo can fallow this guide and make sure if repository exist in your clone url.

http://gitref.org/creating/